# Mapping a texture to a quad opengl and pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I am trying to map a texture to a quad in pyglet using the opengl functions but the quad is just showing up as white.

My code looks like this:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
image = pyglet.image.load("redbrick.png")
texture = image.get_texture()
```

and my draw function:

```
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13)
    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i (0, 0)
    glVertex2i (0, 0)
    glTexCoord2i (1, 0)
    glVertex2i (100, 0)
    glTexCoord2i (1, 1)
    glVertex2i (100, 100)
    glTexCoord2i (0, 1)
    glVertex2i (0, 100)
    glEnd ()
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing out for it to be drawn as a white quad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few things that may be wrong. It would be nice to have the full code in like a pastebin but I can't comment to ask so...

your texture needs to be made into an opengl texture. You need to first convert your image into a raw data format. When you load the image do image.get_data(), compressed into a single line below. This isn't the most efficient way but a simple example.

After Binding the texture set drawing parameters.

Then hand the data to the video card in glTexImage2D.

```
data=pyglet.image.load("redbrick.png").get_data()
texture_id = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (image_width), (image_height), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)
```

After that you should be able to use this texture if you bind with texture_id. 13 could be nothing for all I can see. Provide all the code and I could probably revise.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, that's really helpful. The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/naw7wXs5 (before any changes were made)

Comment: It tells me get_data() takes 2 arguments :/ What do I use for that?

Comment: I've got that sorted now, but I'm getting a "wrong type" error for the glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id) line. It looks like this now: http://pastebin.com/djCM8vvn

Comment: glGenTexture should only have texture_id = glGenTextures(1)

Comment: it says it takes two arguments when I try to run it

Comment: From what I have seen in the pyglet programming guide you can use texture.id instead of glGenTextures(1), does that sound right? :/

Comment: Maybe I wish I knew pyglet but it has little use to me. Just keep trying stuff XD. I can teach a decent amount of OpenGL if you'd be interested.Also python. Kaliber64@hotmail.com.

Comment: Thanks :) I've send you an email if I'm having trouble with OpenGL, it seems such a complex subject! I'm trying to make an rpg from first person perspective but using 2d images. I thought OpenGL would be the best option :)

Comment: Yay I found the problem, I needed to put glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) in the on_draw() function XD

Comment: I see. I've never forgotten that tag so I wouldn't have known what could have cause it. Good Luck. We can collaborate unless you want to do it solo.

Comment: Thanks that would be great, I'll send you an email :)